# Nginx erorr_page on proxy_pass?

Tags: nginx, web-server

Does the built in error handling in NGINX support proxy_pass or upstream servers?

I have tested with variations of error_page 404 /404.html and then location to my static files, however no luck.

The weblogic server downstream is presenting a 404 in the response, but nginx seems to be unable to see this?

is there a way around this? perhaps a $header_response type variable?

Comment: Do you mean "upstream"? WebLogic is an application server...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to use `proxy_intercept_errors on` to do what you'd want to achieve. Ref: https://nginx.org/r/proxy_intercept_errors . Here's the direct quote of what this directive does...

> Determines whether proxied responses with codes greater than or equal
>   to 300 should be passed to a client or be redirected to nginx for
>   processing with the error_page directive.